# return direct download link in django

Tags: django, httpresponse

I have a form with a button to download a ZIP file. My django app returns the direct download URL for the external file, but I have some problems when returning the file:

```
directDownloadLink = site.getDirectDownloadLink(link)
```

I've tried to return the file using:

```
return HttpResponse(directDownloadLink)
```

which returns a blank web page containing the direct link;

```
return HttpResponse(directDownloadLink)
```

which redirects me to the base page where the file is stored;

```
mimetypes.init()
return HttpResponseRedirect(directDownloadLink,
                            mimetype='.zip')
```

which makes me download a 100byte file. The file i'm trying to download is 35kb.

Comment: so what behavior exactly you want? you want to return redirect which will allow users download the whole file?

Comment: how are you serving the download file? is that a static resource or django generates it?

Comment: I have the direct download link to an external file in another server. I want the to allow the users to download that file after clicking in a form button.

Comment: Hi. I'm coming back for the same problem. Let's put an example: i have the following link: http://www.podnapisi.net/en/ppodnapisi/download/i/1537967/k/4468ba748a002b8879f86f76c8032fdac64cc13f, If I paste it in the search bar, I will download a file, but I accomplish this behaviour in django, if returned as httpresponse, then it displays a page with the link.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just do this

```
<a href="{{ file.url }}">download file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out the answer. My problem was that the url I was trying to return had a 302 redirect response. I retrieved the final url link using `urllib` and return it as a simple hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects):

```
response = FileResponse(open('myfile.png', 'rb'))
```